# Publishing Flex app on Google Play with applicationDPI mxml property set

Tags: android, apache-flex

When developing my app, I took the easy approach and set applicationDPI in the main MXML file.
For example, I just set it to 240 when testing on HTC Sensation, and to 320 when testing on iPhone 4.

Now I've made 2 APKs (240 and 320) and was hoping to publish them on Google Play and assign the right devices to them - it does not seem possible.

Has anybody done this? I guess I will need to modify my app to not use MXML-set applicationDPI  and handle asset resizing myself; I was just wondering if there is another way that would work with Google Play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do this Google Play supports multiple APK and you can base the selection on screen density. You need to be in advanced mode for this option.

For more information see.
http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

They do however advise to try and use a single APK.